# Open source social media icons to download and use on website?

Tags: html, css, web, social-media

Where can I find social media icons (preferably in the colours of the respective social media companies' logos) to download and use on a website?

Note: I google (free social media icons download) and almost all results are commercial in nature, and none from the usual web developer sites like github or stack overflow unfortunately.

Suggestions so far:

- [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=socials)

[image]

Font awesome looks great, but isn't in colours of the actual companies, and isn't free (at least, not for heavy use).

- [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/extend/icons/?) from a search, I don't think they offer social media icons, also only single-colour (not the colour of the social media company itself), but it is free

Is there anything that meets the criteria of i) in colour of company's logo, ii) free to download / use?

Comment: You know you can change the color of Font Awesome icons right ? And as far as I know the social media icons are included in the free version

Comment: c'mon, by now you should know, that SO is for specific coding issues only. If you looking for recommendations that SO is the wrong place.

Comment: @sinanspd yep, totally. But I want the actual social media companies' colours, not one colour for all

Comment: @tacoshy 'what's the code to put social media icons in their own colours in html for free...'

Comment: Check out [iconfinder](https://iconfinder.com/search?q=social+media)

Comment: @marsnebulasoup thanks so much. Perfect: https://imgur.com/a/PruVb10 Make an answer if you like

Comment: i do not understand why the question got downvotes. It is a valid question which needs answering. Nevertheless, you can give svgs the colour you desire. And it is true that some fonts in FontAwesome are only on the PRO version available. Alternative, maybe Flaticon could be useful.

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas because it not meet the SO guidelines and he is long enough around to know the guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[iconfinder](https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=social+media) has colored social media icons, available to download and use for free, **though you'd probably need to credit the author**. They also have non-free plans, which might work better if you need access to more than the 300k+ free icons.

Some of their free icons:

[image: icons]

If that doesn't work for you, check out this [list of free social media icon packs](https://buffer.com/library/social-media-icons/).

Comment: Just a follow up to say this solution was perfect. There were two common file formats, `.png`, which most of us are familiar with, and `.webp`, which I hadn't encountered before. The images I used were a mixture of both of those file types, and they work perfectly in a production application. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just another small note to say the `.webp` extension doesn't seem to work well on mobile, so used all `.png` :)